# Turn off FxCop analysis during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We are using C# with VS2017 to develop a desktop application. For the static analysis, we were using Visual Studio's "Code Analysis" functionality. This is invoked using the menu `Analyze->Run Code Analysis`.

Recently I added the package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` to the project to get more analysis. Now I am getting the warnings from the analyzer whenever I build the project. Is there any way to disable this? I would like to get this warning only when I invoke the `Code Analysis` through the menu(as in the VS's built-in analyzer). I tried un-checking the property `Enable Code Analysis on Build` in project properties `Code Analysis` window. But the warning are still shown during the build.

[image]